# What does /** this */ mean in PHP files?

Tags: php, comments

What does `/** this */` mean in PHP files? Does it have some special meaning, or is it treated as a normal multiline comment like `/* comment */`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know they have no special meaning, and are treated as normal multiline comments.

If you were referring to `/** these */` (with a single `*` for the closing delimiter), they're called [PHPDoc comments](http://phpdoc.org). <del>To the PHP interpreter they're still multiline comments, but</del> The PHP interpreter tokenizes these as `T_DOC_COMMENT`, and to many IDEs and the phpDocumentor tool they convey their actual documentative meaning.

Comment: The number of asterisks in the closing tag doesn't matter so long as there is at least one. It's the double-asterisk in `/**` that makes it a docblock.

Comment: Just an extra goodie for most IDE users; `/* @var $variable Type */` is an inline type hint. Good for letting the IDE know what your variables *are* when it's not obvious (like in a `foreach` loop)

Answer (score 0):

No special meaning as such. But it may be used by tools such as PHPDoc to generate documentation.

Comment: PHP actually parses them differently and provides access to them through [reflection's `getDocComment()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getdoccomment.php).